# Multiple Instances of the same class, but don't want them sharing a private variable

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I have a WPF window and class associated with it.. and a few buttons open up a new instance of that class and WPF window

```
season_leaders.T10PassingL temp = new season_leaders.T10PassingL();
```

now there's a private variable in this class that each window has access too.. but when one window changes that variable.. it changes for all the other windows too...

how can i make it so that each window that changes this variable.. doesn't change the other instances of the classes variable?  ie. so each window has its own instance of that variable.  if that makes sense.. o_O

```
public partial class T10PassingL : Window
{
    private string type;
```

EDIT: answered in the comments, thanks guys

Comment: "when one window changes that variable.. it changes for all the other windows too": are you sure about this? The variable is not static, so each instance has its own copy...

Comment: A private variable is unique to each class. Only static variables are shared. You're probably passing around the class instead of creating three classes.

Comment: If you have two instances of a class, they each get their own "copy" (version of) `private string type` since it is not `static`.  They should not be able to affect each other.

Comment: It looks like you've got only one instance of your `T10PassingL` window called from three different places, not three instances.

Comment: whoops you guys are right.  i took out static and it worked. i'm an idiot, thank you guys